# CustomView inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I create custom view on Android. I need to use it as items to the listview.

**My custom view:**

```
public class CustomView extends View{
int random;

//4 constructors;

public int getRandom() {
    return random;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0,0,new Paint());
    drawLetters(new Canvas(b));
}

private void init(){
    drawingUtil = DrawingUtil.getInstance(getContext());
    random = new Random().nextInt();
}

}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    List<String> chapter = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapter(List<String> chapter, Context context) {
        this.chapter = chapter;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        return new ChapterHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ChapterHolder) holder).setVerse(chapter.get(position), position);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": random " + ((ChapterHolder) holder).getRandom());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chapter.size();
    }

}
```

the problem is that the contents of the custom view was repeated. to test I write in the log a random number generated in custom view class. When scrolling through the list that number repeated, even if i only scroll down. What I need to do to make each element do not repeat the contents?

Comment: You are using a recycler view and views get recycled. This gets asked at least 4 times a day, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36780828/1837367 or here as well http://stackoverflow.com/q/36779656/1837367

Answer (score 0):

From the first look of it it seems like you're creating one ViewHolder (ChapterHolder) but you're binding another (RecyclerView.ViewHolder). In your adapter declaration it should be:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ChapterHolder>
```

and then your onBindViewHolder will actually bind the right holder... and will look like this:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChapterHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setVerse(chapter.get(position), position);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ": random " + 
        holder.getRandom());
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code but it still not working. it repeats the same randoms

Comment: Make sure you set the holder position to right position. F.e have mPosition int as class member in ChapterHolder class. Make sure when you bind ViewHolder you pass the position to holder variable. F.e. holder.mPosition=position;

Comment: so, what should I do with this reference?

Comment: well I don't know. Since I don;t see your setChapter method in ChapterHolder. Put theoretically with problem like yours, problem is either in setting the chapter or in the actual list of strings with chapters.